# Is the modelname of a flight management system chosen in accordance with the aircraft it will be used on?

Tags: flight-controls, boeing, fms

I am looking for information about what modules (not necessarly partnumbers) are used in a flight management system of a relatively new airplane.
After having looked around for quite some time, I found this bit of information with a very [nice scheme block](https://www.ltu.se/cms_fs/1.4070!/chap%2018%20flight%20management%20%20%209%20pages.pdf).

The flight management system (FMS) they are talking about is the 737 FCMS. However it is not totally clear to me (even after having looked around online), whether this is the FCMS is the one being used for Boeings 737.

Is this the case? Or is that number just coincidence?

Comment: I can't answer specifically for this case, but generally the FMS is made by a third party and used across multiple aircraft types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the system used on the Boeing 737. As the document mentions, it is similar to the system design on the Boeing 757 and 767 models.

Comment: It was pretty hard to find that information. Why is it so difficult to find some sort of technical info about FMS? This info isn't even from the producers themselves.

Comment: FMS systems are not really standardised, each manufacturer has their own way of doing things. The manuals and technical documentation are copyrighted and subject to non-disclosure agreements. Those who buy aircraft or maintain aircraft systems tend to be careful about information leaking out of their business. There are very few people who have an FMS on their desk to play around with, and those that do are also bound by strict NDAs.

Comment: How does it come that I found this info in that case if it is subject to NDA? So the FSM is not chosen in accordance with the aircraft on which it will be used, right?

Comment: Over time things become public. Airlines go bankrupt, old aircraft are scrapped, documentation gets around.

Comment: @traducerad the document you found is more of a brochure, it's none technical. DL is right, many operators aren't even allowed to open the black boxes (avionics boxes). If you want brochures, plenty of those on the interwebz, Google is your friend.

Comment: Even more than NDA's, it's about $. It costs money to buy an official manual from the manufacturers, and those are copyrighted so that they don't tend to end up in the public domain very quickly or very often. Not to say it never happens, but anything official from Smiths or Honeywell or Boeing probably won't survive on the internet very long.  Less official publications and study guides, maybe slightly more available.